# POSTGIS: lwgeom_clip_to_ordinate_range clipping routine returned NULL

Tags: postgis, linear-referencing

I'm trying to do linear referencing with st_locatebetween.

In the past everything went well.  But from now on, **i get following issue**:

> lwgeom_clip_to_ordinate_range clipping routine returned NULL

Searching on the internet gives me a few results pointing to: [results](https://postgis.net/docs/doxygen/2.1/da/d5a/lwlinearreferencing_8c_a9980ce9ce747bf22606ee67c1db5985d.html).
I don't even know what it means.

I'm using following code to generate the linear reference:

```
SELECT 
a.geometry,
a.ws_oidn,
a.type,
a.morf,
a.wegcat,
a.rstrnm
   FROM ( SELECT st_locatebetween(ws.geom, wv.vanpos, (wv.totpos + 10)) AS geometry,
        ws.ws_oidn,
        wv.type,
        ws.morf,
        ws.wegcat,
        ws.rstrnm
       FROM wegsegment ws
         LEFT JOIN attwegverharding wv ON ws.ws_oidn = wv.ws_oidn) a
```

Comment: can you pinpoint when that started (e.g. after updating any component, data etc.)? could *wv.totpos + 10* be out of range of the geom?

Comment: @ThingumaBob Normaly I work with a materialized view based on all roads of my country.  But now I got an update from one city and i imported them as separate tables.  Trying to do the same linear referencing.  I tried without '+10' and get the same error